# List of list of dicts values to list in python

Tags: python

The order of the resulted list is irrelevant, I need to add the elements afterwards.

```
Input1: [[{'a': 57}], 87] 
Expect Output1: [57,87]

Input2: [[{'a': 57, 'b':12}], 87] 
Expect Output2: [57,12,87]

Input3: [[{'a': 57}], 12, [{'a':34}], 87] 
Expect Output3: [57,12,34,87]
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's Pretty Simple all you Need is to just check the Type of the object

Then If it's a list get the first index of it which is a dict

So for example if i have
`[{1,2,3}]`
It will convert it to Just `{1,2,3}`

Then Looping Through The values`(not the keys)` in the Dict
and just adds it to a list

Whereas If it's not a list then just add it to the list

```py
Input3 = [[{'a': 57}], 12, [{'a':34}], 87] 

li = []

for i in Input3: 
    if type(i) == list:
        for item in i[0].values():
            li.append(item)
        
    else:
        li.append(i)
```